# ExpandableListView.setOnClickListener not working properly

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

### My set-up

---

I have a custom ExpandableListAdapter (that extends BaseExpandableListAdapter), inside of which I am overriding the `isChildSelectable` method and returning `true`:

```
@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

Inside the overrided `onCreateView` method inside my Fragment class I am setting an `onChildClickListener` this way:

```
expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
    @Override
       public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
         try {
           DownloadThisPatientInfo.downloadThisPatientInfo(...);
           return true;
         } catch (NullPointerException e) {
           return false;
         }
       }
});
```

### My problem

---

The code inside `onChildClick` method is not being called.

### What I have tried to detect the problem

---

First of all: the Logcat shows *no errors*, and the program just continues its execution after clicking a child, *as if I didn't click it*. No errors, no warnings, nothing.

I tried setting a breakpoint then going into debugging mode. Breakpoint in line:

```
try {
```

This breakpoint isn't being triggered after a child click. Just in case, I tried making a Log.d(str, str) call just before the `try` block:

```
expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
       Log.d("TESTING", "### Child Clicked.");
       try { ... }
       catch ( ... ) { ... }
});
```

Nothing appears in the Log.

Obviously the code inside `onChildClick` isn't being called. I am sure it must be something quite obvious. Why is this happening? I'll update with more code if it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Consider adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to your item's parent LinearLayout.

Comment: I added to my parent LinearLayout of my Item layout file but didnt help :(